# NLA action modifiers, character walking on curve

Tags: bezier-curves, nla-editor

In the old MancandyFAQ, Bassam shows an action curve modifier for making MC walk on a curve up hill and all. I'm trying to achieve a similar thing in 2.71 but not sure how to go about it. Walk cycle and stepped root bone NLA strips are fine, just wanting to fit vertical movement to terrain in a controlled way.

Anyone know how best to do this in the NLA/action editor in 2.71?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a curve and check *Path animation* and set the evaluation time.

[image]

Add a [*Follow Path Constrained*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Follow_Path) after that you character should look like this

[image]

[image]

With the [*Locked Track*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Tracking/Locked_Track) influence you can control the vertical orientation, I used torso because for some reason I wasn't able to select the root bone.

[image]

Comment: Do you seriously need to use purple in your UI?

Comment: @X-27 The Ubuntu Ambience theme is my default before install the energy theme.